# Who has right of way in a lane merge?

Tags: driving, ohio

When lanes merge on a highway, who has right of way?

Consider the point where the left lane ends, and cars must now must merge into the middle lane.

Who has the right of way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ohio Revised Code 4511.33 (A)(1)

> A vehicle or trackless trolley shall be driven, as nearly as is practicable, entirely within a single lane or line of traffic and shall not be moved from such lane or line until the driver has first ascertained that such movement can be made with safety.

The person changing lanes can't change lanes until it is safe.

Comment: To expand on this, if lanes merge into one there is pretty much always a yellow caution sign that indicates which lane is merging into the other lane. For example, a yellow "Merge Right" sign implies that the right lane does *not* end, but the left lane does and anyone in the left lane should merge over into the right lane. Thus, ascertaining the safety of the merge is entirely on the person in the left lane - the person in the right lane is not changing lanes.